# Type error: " 'module' object is not callable " in attempt to run python test file

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm writing my first selenium python test and I'm stumped with this error. As I understand, the problem is variable/ class names, but I can't solve it.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
    import time, unittest
    binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

    def is_alert_present(wd):
        try:
            wd.switch_to_alert().text
            return True
        except:
            return False

    class test_add_group(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            self.wd = webdriver()
            self.wd.implicitly_wait(60)

        def test_test_add_group(self):
            success = True
            wd = self.wd
            wd.get("http://localhost/addressbook/")
            wd.find_element_by_name("user").click()
            wd.find_element_by_name("user").clear()
            wd.find_element_by_name("user").send_keys("admin")
            wd.find_element_by_name("pass").click()
            wd.find_element_by_name("pass").clear()
            wd.find_element_by_name("pass").send_keys("secret")


        def tearDown(self):
            self.wd.quit()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

Error:

> self = 
>       def setUp(self):
>       self.wd = webdriver()
>       TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: can you post traceback? `self.wd = webdriver()` would be a good candidate for the error.

Comment: I've added it down below

Comment: crystal ball 1 - traceback 1 :) you're trying to instanciate a module when you should instanciate an object of this module (which one, I don't know).

Comment: guessing `self.wd = browser` is what you meant to write? based on `wd.get`?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.wd = webdriver()
```

Is at fault. You have this defined at the top:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

You should be setting `self.wd` to the equivalent of `browser` from the above code

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer so others don't click into your question trying to help. Or, if you have more questions feel free